# How to implement the Maximum or Minimum Searching Algorithm (QUMMSA) circuit in Quirk?

Tags: programming, grovers-algorithm, optimization

I am Java and Python programmer who started self-learning Quantum Computing a couple of months back. The journey has been thus far very tough. I have been using QisKit and Quirk to learn by in addition to Khan academy on the Linear Algebra side.

I have now started to dive a little into the deep and and read research and go through the practise of trying replicate circuits on Quirk then QisKit.

I have come accross the followng paper [An Optimized Quantum Maximum or Minimum Searching Algorithm and its Circuits](https://export.arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1908/1908.07943.pdf)

The paper proposes this QUMMSA algorithm to find the minimum or maximum in a dataset.

What I would love to do is replicate the QUMMSA circuit in Quirk with the Titanic experiment written in the paper but with just two inputs.

How do I best implement the circut?